# plotting Kaplan Meier curve in D3

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Is there a sample for plotting Kaplan Meier curve in D3? I have my dataset with the censor info as well. I am confused as to how to plot it using d3. 
My data is in a csv file.

Comment: You can't plot it directly. You need to generate the data for the actual curve and then plot that.

Answer (score 0):

Please see [Nick Strayer's Block](https://bl.ocks.org/nstrayer/4e613a109707f0487da87300097ca502) for a great example of a KM survival curve:

[image]

> Each bar in the top chart represents an individual's time of entry and
>   exit from a study. The color of the bar indicates which type of exit
>   they had. The bottom chart is a Kaplan-Meier survival curve
>   representing the "survival" of individuals at a given time point. E.g.
>   If the K-M curve = 0.7 at a time of 6 years then 70% of individuals
>   have yet to have the event of study at that time (have survived).
>
> Drag the grey bar across the x-axis to regenerate the K-M curve for
>   the individuals who entered the study past the filter point.
>
> The fact that the survival curve drops to 0 almost immediately when
>   considering all the data illustrates a pitfall of non-parametric
>   methods for generating a survival curve when you have left truncated
>   data. By filtering the data that the curve is generated with, we are
>   generating a conditional survival curve, or he survival curve for an
>   individual given that they have survived to time t.